# What is the advantage of using Bootstrap together with HTML5Boilerplate?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, html5boilerplate

I know this question has come up several times before in many different forms but I still can't find the answer I'm looking for.

Why do people recommend combining Bootstrap with HTML5Boilerplate? What benefits do you get that are not already in Bootstrap's own boilerplate?

People keep saying they are two different things but I don't really agree. They even share some of the most important things like Normalize.css and the standard meta tags. It just seems redundant.

Answer (score 3):

HTML5Boilerplate is a starting template which combines what is currently thought of as good practices. 
Bootstrap is a CSS, HTML and JS toolkit you can use in existing projects.

So, bootstrap will give you element styling and responsive design. I throw this into any project if I feel lazy.

HTML5Boilerplate is more of a beginner/intermediate guide to developers who wants to see what is the most modern approach to things.